# Android Studio - New Activity called from OnPostExecute() not opening

Tags: android

I've been working on this issue for a few hours with no success. I have also referenced other StackOverflow questions and not found a solution.

When I call my new activity from my async task onPostExecute() method, the new activity does not open. It is listed in my manifest. The button clicks but the screen does not switch to the new activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    Button editprofile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilebutton);
    editprofile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ProfileTask().execute();
        }
    });


    //search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); //setup variable
}

public void Go(View view) {

}

//public void Edit(View view) {
    //this.startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
//}

public void Viewcart(View view) {
    //
}

public void Logout(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private class ProfileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context context;

    protected void onpreExecute() {} //parent class

    @Override //do not want to call parent method. use super if you want both
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            //search for phrase
            //php script to call
            String link = "http://people.aero.und.edu/~lwingate/457/2/profile_get.php";

            //get method to pass variables
            link += "?username=" + URLEncoder.encode("customer", "UTF-8");
            link += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode("testing", "UTF-8");

            //Connect to server
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Read server response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { //result of background computation passed here after doneif (result!=null) { //if returns with data, entry exists. login successful
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileResultsActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        //Intent newintent = new Intent();
        //newintent.setClass(context, SearchResultsActivity.class);
        //context.startActivity(newintent);
        //context.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchResultsActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

```
LogCat:
04-28 21:21:27.055 29642-29642/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-28 21:21:27.055 29642-29642/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-28 21:21:27.183 29642-29642/com.example.aplicacaodelivros W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.aplicacaodelivros-2/lib/x86
04-28 21:21:27.201 29642-29642/com.example.aplicacaodelivros I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-28 21:21:27.337 29642-29670/com.example.aplicacaodelivros I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-28 21:21:27.337 29642-29670/com.example.aplicacaodelivros D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-28 21:21:27.338 29642-29670/com.example.aplicacaodelivros W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-28 21:21:27.338 29642-29670/com.example.aplicacaodelivros D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
04-28 21:21:29.761 29642-29642/com.example.aplicacaodelivros W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-28 21:21:30.695 29642-29642/com.example.aplicacaodelivros W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this if not working show your logcat.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileResultsActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

 Change your code below this

 Intent intent = new Intent(Yourclassnname.this,ProfileResultsActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I've tried what I think is every possible combination of sending an intent and none have worked. The log is added above (below my code)

Comment: You are trying to do Post method or GET method @codequeen

Comment: I am attempting the GET method

Comment: catch(Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } Instance of this put like this  catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception: ","print****   " + e.getMessage());
        } First check what exception is through and one more thing check logcat  Log.d("responce","**** "+sb.toString()); try this

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ProfileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { private Context context; protected void onpreExecute(Context context) {this.context=context;
}
```

in onpostexecute method write it as

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)  { Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProfileResultsActivity.class); intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); context. startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Or else in onpostexecute method use getApplicationContext in the place of context.

Comment: I've tried both of these but no success :( I think I'm going back to the drawing board on this project.